# Facebook look alike app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, split, screen

I'm currently developing an iPhone app that should support some features found in the Facebook App for iPhone.
[image]

I want to support a UINavigationController with a UIBarButtonItem on top right, wich opens an overlayer view that looks like a splitscreen on iPad (or seen here in the picture of the Facebook iPhone app when the notifications button is pressed).

The problem I have is that UISplitScreenController is not supported on iPhone, so I wonder how Facebook achieves that.

Anybody has an Idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe they Open a top level forground UI View which has 100% Transparency as the Background Color. Then draw a box with the triangle area indented in the window?

If you get this working maybe you could post the code?

Comment: I have already thought of that...
I will continue searching some solution for this before I start building something like this on my own.
I will tell you as soon as I found a solution. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this on my own.
With my awesome photoshop skills i designed an image that looks like the background of the UISplitscreen from iPads. then i added a UITableView, style plain and rounded rects.

[image: MyCustomSplitViewForIPhone]

I think I'm gonne improve it a little further to give it a better look, but actually I'm quite happy about the result :)